# UnicodeDecodeError: utf-8 codec cant decode byte: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

There are database MS SQL. It has a stored procedure that displays the entire contents of the table. When you try to call this procedure from the python, the error takes off:

> UnicodeDecodeError: utf8 codec can not decode byte 0xc2 in position 0:
>   invalid continuation byte.

It connects the base itself is normal, Trouble only with the stored procedure.
To work with a database using a library `pyodbc`.

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER{FreeTDS};SERVER=sql_srv_name;UID=login;PWD=pass;DATABASE=web_db")
curs = conn.cursor()
result = curs.execute("EXEC proc_name")

print result.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but you want to convert each line returned to ascii, something like

```
for s in result.fetchall():
    t = s.encode("ascii", "replace")
    print t
```